# Grails asset-pipeline not picking up resource requirements

Tags: javascript, grails, asset-pipeline

I have a Grails (2.3.6) app and have configured it to use `asset-pipeline`:

```
// BuildConfig.groovy
plugins {
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.7"
}
```

In my `grails-app/assets/javascripts` directory, I have:

- `myapp.js`
- `fizz.js`
- `buzz.js`

Then in my `grails-app/views/index.gsp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'myapp.css')}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="home" class="page">
            <!-- Content... -->
        </div>
        <asset:javascript src="myapp.js" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And finally, in my `myapp.js`:

```
= require fizz.js
= require buzz.js
= require_self

// INITIALIZE THE APPLICATION.
init();

function init() {
    alert("Do stuff!");
}
```

When I do a `grails run-app`, the app starts up just fine. When I go to view the page source (for `index.gsp`) I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/myapp.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="home" class="page">
            <!-- Content... -->
        </div>
        <script src="/assets/myapp.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I click on the `/assets/myapp.js?compile=false` link, to view its source, I get the exact same JS as above:

```
= require fizz.js
= require buzz.js
= require_self

// INITIALIZE THE APPLICATION.
init();

function init() {
    alert("Do stuff!");
}
```

So not only is `asset-pipeline` *not* translating these `require` statements at the top of `myapp.js` and pulling in the specified JS files, but its also not stripping the `require`s out either. How can I configure the plugin to correctly pull in my other JS libs (`fizz.js` and `buzz.js`)?

Answer (score 2):

There is an appropriate syntax that needs to be used with the `require` directives when using asset-pipeline.

This is how `myapp.js` should start with (without an empty first line):

```
//= require fizz.js
//= require buzz.js
//= require_self
```

Refer [Usage documentations](http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/) in detail.

Answer (score -1):

After implementing what #dmahapatro answered, your page source should automatically show

```
 !DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/myapp.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="home" class="page">
        <!-- Content... -->
    </div>
    <script src="/assets/myapp.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script><script src="/assets/fizz.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script><script src="/assets/buzz.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code snippet bellow

```
    /*
     *= require fizz.js
    */
```

tells makes asset pipeline to add the fizz.js file as a linked script in the header when you open your a page on your App

This also applies to css files as the case may be.

Comment: On gsp pages you include your assets with the assetpipeline taglib <asset:script src="fizz.js"/>. I prefer to place global scripts in the layout only specifying the js manifest files, however the above taglib works for adding additional files not in the manifest on specific pages as well. 

My layout file would include something like this in the head.
<asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>